# Local connectedness in the boundary implies local connectedness in the closure

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Given a locally connected topological space $X$, and $A \subset X$ such that the boundary of $A$ is locally connected, is true that the closure of $A $ is also locally connected?
I tried hard to prove this without success. Any help?
Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by locally connected?

Comment: A topological space is locally connected if it has a basis formed by connected open sets, that is, if for every open set U and $x \in U$, there exists a connected open set V such that $x \in V \subset U$. Above boundary of A and clausure of A are considered with the subspace topology.

Comment: What about the topological sine curve?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma As far as I know, the topologist's sine curve is its own boundary and it is not locally connected, so it would not work as a counterexample. Am I correct?

Comment: @AndrésIbáñezNúñez take the full topologist's sine as a space in its own right. The right hand part $A$ has $\{0}\times [-1,-1]$ as its boundary, which is locally connected, but $\overline{A}$ is not.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma. Letting  X be the topologist's sine curve does not fit the hypothesis of the Q, that X be locally connected.

Answer (score 5):

It is true.

Under your assumptions we show that $\overline A$ is locally connected.

First note that $\overline A\setminus \partial A$ is open in $X$, so it follows from local connectedness of $X$ that $\overline A$ is locally connected at each point of $\overline A\setminus \partial A$.

Now let $x\in \partial A$ and let $U'$ be any $\overline A$-open neighborhood of $x$. We want to find a connected $\overline A$-open neighborhood of $x$ that is contained in $U'$.

Since $\partial A$ is locally connected, there is a connected $\partial A$-open $V'\subseteq U'\cap \partial A$ with $x\in V'$.

Let $V$ be an open subset of $X$ such that $V\cap \partial A=V'$.

For each $y\in V'$ let $W_y$ be a connected open subset of $X$ such that $y\in W_y\subseteq U\cap V$, where $U$ is open in $X$ such that $U\cap \overline A=U'$.

Let $W=\bigcup _{y\in V'}W_y$.  It is easy to see that $W$ is connected.

$W':=W\cap \overline A$ is our desired set.  Clearly $W'$ is open in $\overline A$ and $W'\subseteq U'$. To complete the proof we just need...

Claim: $W'$ is connected.

Note that $W'=V'\cup (W'\setminus V')$. If $C$ is a relatively clopen subset of  $W'$ that meets $V'$, then $V'\subseteq C$.  If $C$ does not also contain $W'\setminus V'$, then the two sets $$W'\setminus  C$$ $$C\cup (W\setminus \overline A)$$ form a disconnection of $W$, a contradiction.  Thus $W'\subseteq C$.  This proves the claim.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I see the point.

Comment: In fact there are other ways of finding such a W. One can take W to be the component of x in the intersection of U and V, wich is open because X is locally  connected.